# SIP Packet Parsing using python

Tags: python-3.x, sip, voip, scapy, pyshark

I have a pcap file captured during the VOIP call. From this file, I would like to filter out only the SIP packets and I would like to parse the SIP packets to read the information present in the "SIP message Header" and "SIP Message body" using python.

Any suggestions/sample code would be really helpful.

Comment: Please let me know if the my answer helped you solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna try it now

Comment: I looked at your errors, which **ARE NOT** being produced by my 21 lines of code.  Please post the code that you're using so that I can help you troubleshoot your errors.

Comment: Can you share your *pcap file*?

Comment: I can't share my PCAP file. I will find a sample pcap file with SIP messages. After running the same on the sample file, I will share both the Code and the output of SIP Header & SIP body.

Comment: My code so far has produced zero errors.  What type of SIP packages (Vendor?) does your pcap have?

Comment: I reworked my code to use a ZIP function.  I have tested this code with 8 different PCAP files that have SIP packets.  My code produced no errors,  I did note that all  of my PCAP have an empty *sip.msg_body.*.  It's hard for me to troubleshoot your problems without having access to your PCAP file.

Comment: Can you pls share your pcap file so that I can try at my end?

Comment: I used these [Wireshark pcap samples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#SIP_and_RTP) in my tests.

Comment: I was looking at the errors you posted on [GitHub Pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/467).  These errors are related to *asyncio* and not my code.  I also noted that your errors seem to be thrown on Microsoft Windows.  Are you running a Windows-based OS?

Comment: Have you looked through [Python Bugs](https://bugs.python.org/) for potential answers to your *asyncio* issues?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows based OS.

Comment: I have not checked the python bugs. I will check them now.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the "SIP message Header" and "SIP Message body" of a SIP packet by querying the field names and field values for the packet.

Here is one way to do this.

```
import pyshark
import asyncio

pcap_file = 'sip.pcap'

capture = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_file)
for packet in capture:
    try:
        if hasattr(packet, 'sip'):
            field_names = packet.sip._all_fields
            field_values = packet.sip._all_fields.values()
            for field_name, field_value in zip(field_names, field_values):
                if field_name == 'sip.msg_hdr':
                    print(str(field_value.split('\\xd\\xa')))
                elif field_name == 'sip.msg_body':
                    print(field_value)
    except OSError:
        pass
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
```

*sip.msg_hdr* output from my code above

```
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2118-1-0', 'From: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'Contact: sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'Content-Type: application/sdp', 'Content-Length:   126', '', 'v=0', 'o=- 42 42 IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 's=-', 'c=IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 't=0 0', 'm=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 99', 'a=rtpmap:99 L16/8000/2', 'a=recvonly', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2118-1-0', 'From: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2118-1-0', 'From: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=yHyF9Hv4UgZ3D', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'Contact: <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060;transport=udp>', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Accept: application/sdp', 'Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE', 'Supported: timer, path, replaces', 'Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer', 'Content-Type: application/sdp', 'Content-Disposition: session', 'Content-Length: 229', 'Remote-Party-ID: "test" <sip:test@10.0.2.15>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no', '', 'v=0', 'o=FreeSWITCH 1480145952 1480145953 IN IP4 10.0.2.15', 's=FreeSWITCH', 'c=IN IP4 10.0.2.15', 't=0 0', 'm=audio 26628 RTP/AVP 99 101', 'a=rtpmap:99 L16/8000/2', 'a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000', 'a=fmtp:101 0-16', 'a=sendonly', 'a=ptime:20', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2118-1-5', 'From: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=yHyF9Hv4UgZ3D', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 ACK', 'Contact: sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.15;rport;branch=z9hG4bKyFcaSgFpvZS6c', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'From: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=yHyF9Hv4UgZ3D', 'To: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 99750230 BYE', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE', 'Supported: timer, path, replaces', 'Reason: Q.850;cause=16;text="NORMAL_CLEARING"', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.15;rport;branch=z9hG4bKyFcaSgFpvZS6c', 'From: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=yHyF9Hv4UgZ3D', 'To: "L16/8000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'Call-ID: 1-2118@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 99750230 BYE', 'Contact: <sip:10.0.2.20:5060;transport=UDP>', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2120-1-0', 'From: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'Contact: sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'Content-Type: application/sdp', 'Content-Length:   127', '', 'v=0', 'o=- 42 42 IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 's=-', 'c=IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 't=0 0', 'm=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 99', 'a=rtpmap:99 L16/16000/2', 'a=recvonly', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2120-1-0', 'From: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2120-1-0', 'From: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=ZtQ8aDD8rSNpS', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'Contact: <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060;transport=udp>', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Accept: application/sdp', 'Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE', 'Supported: timer, path, replaces', 'Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer', 'Content-Type: application/sdp', 'Content-Disposition: session', 'Content-Length: 230', 'Remote-Party-ID: "test" <sip:test@10.0.2.15>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no', '', 'v=0', 'o=FreeSWITCH 1480148506 1480148507 IN IP4 10.0.2.15', 's=FreeSWITCH', 'c=IN IP4 10.0.2.15', 't=0 0', 'm=audio 24082 RTP/AVP 99 101', 'a=rtpmap:99 L16/16000/2', 'a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000', 'a=fmtp:101 0-16', 'a=sendonly', 'a=ptime:20', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2120-1-5', 'From: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=ZtQ8aDD8rSNpS', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 ACK', 'Contact: sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.15;rport;branch=z9hG4bKZr52tB0SS8FSr', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'From: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=ZtQ8aDD8rSNpS', 'To: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 99750234 BYE', 'User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.12-20-b91a0a6~64bit', 'Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE', 'Supported: timer, path, replaces', 'Reason: Q.850;cause=16;text="NORMAL_CLEARING"', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.15;rport;branch=z9hG4bKZr52tB0SS8FSr', 'From: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>;tag=ZtQ8aDD8rSNpS', 'To: "L16/16000/2" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'Call-ID: 1-2120@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 99750234 BYE', 'Contact: <sip:10.0.2.20:5060;transport=UDP>', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
['Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.2.20:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-2121-1-0', 'From: "L16/11025" <sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060>;tag=1', 'To: test <sip:test@10.0.2.15:5060>', 'Call-ID: 1-2121@10.0.2.20', 'CSeq: 1 INVITE', 'Contact: sip:sipp@10.0.2.20:5060', 'Max-Forwards: 70', 'Content-Type: application/sdp', 'Content-Length:   125', '', 'v=0', 'o=- 42 42 IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 's=-', 'c=IN IP4 10.0.2.20', 't=0 0', 'm=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 99', 'a=rtpmap:99 L16/11025', 'a=recvonly', '']
truncated...
```

I have tested the code above with multiple *pcap files* that contain *SIP packets*.  In testing the code produced no errors.

You will need to filters your packets based on your use case.

Here are the items in my SIP packets:

```
sip.Request-Line
sip.Method
sip.r-uri
sip.r-uri.user
sip.r-uri.host
sip.r-uri.port
sip.resend
sip.msg_hdr
sip.Via
sip.Via.transport
sip.Via.sent-by.address
sip.Via.rport
sip.Via.branch
sip.Max-Forwards
sip.From
sip.display.info
sip.from.addr
sip.from.user
sip.from.host
sip.from.port
sip.from.tag
sip.tag
sip.To
sip.to.addr
sip.to.user
sip.to.host
sip.to.port
sip.to.tag
sip.Call-ID
sip.call_id_generated
sip.CSeq
sip.CSeq.seq
sip.CSeq.method
sip.User-Agent
sip.Allow
sip.Supported
sip.Reason
sip.reason_protocols
sip.reason_cause_q850
sip.reason_text
sip.Content-Length


_ws.expert
sip.unrecognized_header
_ws.expert.message
_ws.expert.severity
_ws.expert.group
sip.msg_body
sdp.version
sdp.owner
sdp.owner.username
sdp.owner.sessionid
sdp.owner.version
sdp.owner.network_type
sdp.owner.address_type
sdp.owner.address
sdp.session_name
sdp.connection_info
sdp.connection_info.network_type
sdp.connection_info.address_type
sdp.connection_info.address
sdp.time
sdp.time.start
sdp.time.stop
sdp.media
sdp.media.media
sdp.media.port_string
sdp.media.port
sdp.media.proto
sdp.media.format
sdp.media_attr
sdp.media_attribute.field
sdp.mime.type
sdp.sample_rate
sdp.fmtp.parameter
sdp.media_attribute.value
```

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    macOS
Python:      3.8.0
Pyshark:     0.4.3
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried the above code and while running, got the below error.
Error on reading from the event loop self pipe
loop: <ProactorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 777, in _loop_self_reading
    f = self._proactor.recv(self._ssock, 4096)

Comment: File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 445, in recv
    self._register_with_iocp(conn)
  File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 718, in _register_with_iocp
    _overlapped.CreateIoCompletionPort(obj.fileno(), self._iocp, 0, 0)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Comment: I don't understand what  is causing the errors in *proactor_events.py* and *windows_events.py* .  I added some error handling to my code to see if these errors can be bypassed.   Please let me know what happens.

Comment: Sure, will check and let you know

Comment: Still I can see  the same error with the new code aswell.
Error on reading from the event loop self pipe
loop: <ProactorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 777, in _loop_self_reading
    f = self._proactor.recv(self._ssock, 4096)

Comment: File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 445, in recv
    self._register_with_iocp(conn)
  File "C:\Users\vijayakb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 718, in _register_with_iocp
    _overlapped.CreateIoCompletionPort(obj.fileno(), self._iocp, 0, 0)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Comment: (1) What version of Python and Pyshark are you using?

Comment: (2) Are you using my code with FileCapture or LiveCapture?

Comment: (3) Are you using my 21 lines of code by themselves or within another script?

Comment: Python is 3.9.0 & Pyshark is pyshark-0.4.3.

I'm using your code for file capture and not using your code with any other script.

Comment: I noticed an issue with the code, The same information is captured in both sip_header & sip_body.

It is not capturing only SIP header related info in "sip_header" and SIP body related info in "sip_body".

Comment: You need to filter the values according to your use case.  I posted a list of *field names* to extract values from.